# Custom rewrite rule for backend/admin?

Tags: url-rewriting, wp-admin, rewrite-rules

I would like to create a custom rewrite rule that will take the URL:

`http://domain/submit-project/add`

but display

`http://domain/wp/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=project`

Is there any way to do this? I am trying to add the rewrite rule so in my theme's `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_rules' );

function add_custom_rules() {
  add_rewrite_rule(
    "^submit-project/add",  
        "/wp/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=project",  
        "top");
}
```

I've tried flushing the rules, but this always seems to enter some kind of loop always going back to the 'login' page.

**Edit**

1. The URL is actually just 404-ing now
2. I should add that I do have a page with the slug `submit-project` and thus the URL: `http://domain.com/submit-project` in case it matters.
3. I've installed the plugin Rewrite Rules Inspector and can't seem to find my rule in there.

Comment: Rewrite rules that don't start with `index.php` get written to .htaccess instead of being added to the rule array. I'm not entirely sure it would work anyway, since there would probably be issues with the admin cookies working outside of the admin directory and (if using any kind of domain mapping) cross-domain cookie issues as well.

Comment: Hm, if I'm not mistaken, if the user is not logged in, wouldn't visiting the URL simply forward the user to the login page anyhow? Or is that the issue, that it wouldn't be able to read the cookie even if the user was logged in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, it is possible, but you need to define `ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH` in your `wp-config.php` to the value `/` which might cause security issues.

First of all define this rewrite rules in your .htaccess right before the rewrite rule of wordpress:

```
# Make sure, there is a trailing slash
RewriteRule ^submit-project/add$ submit-project/add/ [R=301,L]
# mask the urls
RewriteRule ^submit-project/add/$ /wp/wp-admin/post-new.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^submit-project/add/post.php?$ /wp/wp-admin/post.php [L,QSA]
# this is the wordpress rule:
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Now you need to define the constant in the `wp-config.php`

```
define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/' );
```

I recommend not to use this on a productive site. Consider to offer a special input formular in the frontend using shortcodes or something less invasive than the shown example.

Comment: This worked perfectly. You were right, it has to do with the ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH.